# backbonejs- not able to render the fields of collection object when json response is wrapped with domain book

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

When below json data is received the view and html code renders the values correctly in the html page.

**JSON DATA**

```
[{"id":"1234","name":"book1","type":"catg1"},{"id":"1235","name":"book2","type":"catg1"},
        {"id":"1236","name":"book3","type":"catg1"},
        {"id":"1237","name":"book4","type":"catg1"},
        {"id":"1238","name":"book5","type":"catg1"}]
```

**Collection and Model**

```
var books= Backbone.Collection.extend({
      url: '/books'
    });

    var Book= Backbone.Model.extend({
      urlRoot: '/books'
    });
```

**VIEW**

```
var bookListView = Backbone.View.extend({
          el: '.page',
          render: function () {
            var that = this;
            var books= new Books();
            books.fetch({
              success: function (banks) {
                var template = _.template($('#book-list-template').html(), {books: books.models});
                that.$el.html(template);
              }
            })
          }
        });
```

**HTML rendered using above Templet**

```
 <% _.each(books, function(book) { %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= htmlEncode(book.get('id')) %></td>
            <td><%= htmlEncode(book.get('name')) %></td>
            <td><%= htmlEncode(book.get('type')) %></td>

        <% }); %>
```

However, I tried various approaches to do the similar thing with the below Json response but failed. Can anyone explain what should I alter in the logic if the Json DATA comes as below

```
    {"book":[{"id":"1234","name":"book1","type":"catg1"},
{"id":"1235","name":"book2","type":"catg1"},
    {"id":"1236","name":"book3","type":"catg1"},
    {"id":"1237","name":"book4","type":"catg1"},
    {"id":"1238","name":"book5","type":"catg1"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone collections by default assume an array in the response of a `.fetch` call.  So changing it to a JSON structure means you need to parse the data first.  Overriding the `parse` function for your collection should solve your problems.  See http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse for more info.

```
var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var books= Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '/books',
  model: Book,
  parse: function(data) {
    return data.book;
  }
});
```

You can add any additional error/parsing that you see fit inside of that parse function.  The response type should be the array of Book JSON.

Comment: what else I have to change...how about the iterator for each?..and View ...var BankListView = Backbone.View.extend({
      el: '.page',
      render: function () {
        var that = this;
        var banks = new Banks();
        banks.fetch({
          success: function (banks) {
            var template = _.template($('#bank-list-template').html(), {banks: banks.models});
            that.$el.html(template);
          }
        })
      }
    });

Comment: You don't *have* to change anything.  As you get more proficient at backbone and programming in general, you can look into event handling (http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on) and initializing the Books collection outside of the render function, so that the render function only does what it's meant to do (render things, not fetch them from the server).

Comment: lastly, last can this parsing be done on the Model also??

Comment: Yes, both Backbone.Collection and Backbone.Model have parse functions that you can override.